# Update a model attribute with a simple link (link_to) in Rails 3 via AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ujs

As a Task management app user, I would like to click a "Completed" link on a Task to record the Task's resolution as completed.

I want this to be an AJAX request using the Rails 3 way of Unobtrusive JavaScript (UJS).  I have been debugging this for quite a while now, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Here is the link_to call I am making inside the view:

```
<%= link_to "Completed", task_path(:id => task.id, :resolution => "completed"), :remote => true, :method => :put %>
```

And here is the update method in my tasks controller:

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :js

  def update
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    @task.update_attributes(params[:task])
    respond_with(@task)
  end
end
```

Watching the Network traffic with Chrome's Dev Tools it appears that the Put request is being made to the proper URL, including the URL parameter (tasks/{:id}?resolution=completed), but the Preview is showing the following error message:

```
Template is missing

Missing template tasks/update, application/update with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. 

Searched in: * "C:/Documents and Settings/Corey Quillen/My Documents/Software Engineering/Projects/Cleaner Card/cleaner_card/app/views"
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to make the resolution an attribute of the task - then it will update:

```
<%= link_to "Completed", task_path(:id => task.id, "task[resolution]" => "completed"), :remote => true, :method => :put %>
```

In rails 4 - preferred method is :patch for an update.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the response of update method in `update.js.erb`.

Place that file at `app/views/tasks/update.js.erb`.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  That did get rid of the error, but the attribute is still not being updated in the database.  Do I need to change something in the controller?

Comment: Try to debug the params in the controller. Can you paste the params that are passed to the controller?

Comment: I decided to embed a hidden form with a hidden form field to update the attribute and that works.  Thanks for your help.